# Parsing a number with more than 10 digits in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate UPC codes using C as a language, but I'm now having a problem with the precision. I tried int, float, long long, etc.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float upc;

    printf("Enter UPC:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &upc);
    printf("upc = %f ", upc);
}
```

the results are :

```
Enter UPC code:
123456789012
upc = 123456790528.000000 d= 1
Process returned 30 (0x1E)   execution time : 6.672 s
Press any key to continue.
```

How can I show the number as is? It's only 12 digits. 
I'm using CodeBlocks, is there an IDE that can handle this better?

Note: please don't tell me to just use `char`! I want to make some calculations later.

Comment: Note that you have to use a different modifier for `scanf` depending on the type you're reading.

Comment: `scanf ("%f", &upc);`

Comment: what is your desired output in this case ?

Comment: i already tried that, thank you for replying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Universal product codes are not subject to integer arithmetic operations, so it doesn't entirely make sense to represent them using `int`. Each digit is assigned a [particular meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code), so a string makes more sense.

If you really just want a band-aid, `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>` will always be able to hold a 12-digit number. Do not use a floating-point type, though, as they are not designed to hold exact integers, but rather to approximate real numbers.

The correct way to use `uint64_t` with `printf` and `scanf` is with the fixed-width format specifiers from `<inttypes.h>`:

```
scanf ( "%" SCNd64, &upc);
printf("upc = %" PRId64 "\n", upc);
```

Answer (score 2):

A `float` can typically store just 6-7 decimal digits.  A 32-bit `int` can store 9 digits (10 if the leading digits is 3 or less).  To store a 12-digit integer, you need to use either a `long long` (up to 18 digits) or perhaps a `double` (up to 15-16 digits), though a `double` is less desirable.

Hence:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long upc;

    printf("Enter UPC:\n");
    scanf ("%lld", &upc);
    printf("upc = %lld\n", upc);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually can you be more clear of what you want as your output? I suggest you one modification in to use long long int instead of float.